Validation formula conflict
In a particular column (DateRangeofReport) of a Sharepoint list I have a validation formula that ensures the input is entered consistently. Additionally, the input is optional, established by disabling "Require that this column contains information". However, existing data won't delete after I click save on an edit.
Here's the formula if anyone can see the issue:
=OR(
    ISBLANK(DateRangeofReport), 
    AND(
        LEN(DateRangeofReport)=23,
        MID(DateRangeofReport,3,1)="/",
        MID(DateRangeofReport,6,1)="/",
        MID(DateRangeofReport,16,1)="/",
        MID(DateRangeofReport,19,1)="/",
        MID(DateRangeofReport,11,1)=" ",
        MID(DateRangeofReport,12,1)="-",
        MID(DateRangeofReport,13,1)=" ",
        ISNUMBER(VALUE(MID(DateRangeofReport,1,2))),
        ISNUMBER(VALUE(MID(DateRangeofReport,4,2))),
        ISNUMBER(VALUE(MID(DateRangeofReport,7,4))),
        ISNUMBER(VALUE(MID(DateRangeofReport,14,2))),
        ISNUMBER(VALUE(MID(DateRangeofReport,17,2))),
        ISNUMBER(VALUE(MID(DateRangeofReport,20,4)))
    )
)


Existing data (column values) will not be deleted if you add validation formula in column settings. If you want to delete the column value for all list items one time, you can do it programmatically. This validation formula will be applied only when you are adding a new list item OR editing an existing list item. It will not be applied to all existing items automatically.

Well, there you go!
